# visibility:hidden doesn't seem to work under IE, Chrome or safari

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

In summary,
Requirement:
If data present populate div with text
If not data present hide div but retain overall table vertical height

Implementation:

**html:**

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <div id= 'div_car_close_out' class='car_close_out'></div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**css:**

```
div.car_close_out {
  border: 2px inset #D5D0D0;
  text-align: left ;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  height:35px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

**javascript:**

```
if (arr_task[0].CarClosedOutDate == " ") {
  document.getElementById("div_car_close_out").style="visibility:hidden";
} else {
  document.getElementById("div_car_close_out").innerHTML = arr_task[0].CarCloseOut;
  document.getElementById("div_car_close_out").style="visibility:visible";
}
```

This works perfectly in FF
However in Chrome, IE and Safari div element is not hidden.

It is possible to use visibility:collapse, but then overall table vertical size is reduced, and positioning of elements below is not correct.

I've failed to find any solution to this seemingly simple requirement. Can any make any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried opacity: 0; ?

Comment: you set it visible on the last line, always. it's NOT part of your conditional flow. i suggesting adding braces to your IFs.

Comment: Please review the HTML you provided above. You don't close the div tag in question, nor is there any content in it. Your JavaScript is fine and works in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the hidden row has no contents, so the browser assigns a smaller amount of vertical space to it than the rows with text in them. It has nothing to do with the visibility, since the same thing happens when the row is visible.

When you change it to `visibility: hidden;`, make sure it still has contents. Put `&nbsp;` in it if you need a placeholder.

```js
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("div_car_close_out").innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
  document.getElementById("div_car_close_out").style = "visibility:hidden";
};
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id='div_car_close_out' class='car_close_out'>Row 2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="button">
  Hide row 2
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The visible value of visibility property is supported for Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera and Safari.

However you can use `visibilitY:initial`, but it's no supported by IE.

You can consult the [Developer Mozilla Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) for detailed information about this property and his possibles values.